# Hook to change the Success message after CiviCRM submits a form?

Tags: extension, hooks, redirect

I'm writing an extension implementing hook_civicrm_post to move contributions from individual to household if the individual is part of a household. However, I'd like the form to either redirect to the HOUSEHOLD summary or to display something about the household in the Successfully saved status message popup so the user doesn't think the contribution entry failed.

Any ideas how I can do either of those things from the extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redirect using the

```
CRM_Utils_System::redirect($urlyouwant)
```

and use

```
CRM_Utils_System::url
```

to build the url itself.

you can as well display pop up messages using CRM.alert() or CRM.status()

That page describes the options or how to call them from php too:
http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Notifications+and+Confirmations

Answer (score 4):

Xavier's answer is generally right but because you are in the context of a form I advise *don't* use the function `CRM_Utils_System::redirect` because that is a rather blunt instrument, and breaks pop-ups and other ajax-based forms (which don't follow the normal round-trip webpage lifecycle). Instead from your hook you can call `CRM_Core_Session::singleton()->pushUserContext($urlYouWant);` and the form controller will take care of doing the actual redirect or other appropriate action.

So from your hook you'd do:

```
$url = CRM_Utils_System::url('civicrm/my/path', 'argumet=1');
CRM_Core_Session::singleton()->pushUserContext($url);
CRM_Core_Session::setStatus(ts('Your foo has been barred'), ts('Saved'), 'success');
```