# What's the recommended way to handle redirection after quickform submissions?

Tags: developer

I often find myself writing calls to CRM_Utils_Redirect in my postProcess methods.

But in core code I don't see this. I see the use of methods like $session->replaceUserContext and postProcess functions that end seemingly without telling me where to go next.

I feel like CiviCRM is often clever enough to go to load different pages on form submission based on where you came from. I have no solid proof of that but lets give Civi the benefit of the doubt on that one :)

I'm guessing there is a structure somewhere that is telling CiviCRM what page to load next but I have failed to spot what that is.

I'm interested in the canonical way that CiviCRM does this (if there is a canoncial way) and knowing how legacy that is, and also what I *should* be doing.

If anyone could enlighten me, I'd be grateful :)

PS. I am not so interested in "you should write that in angular" enlightenment, at least not in the answer to this question.

Comment: just wanted to reference this answer: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/2200/133 for anyone that comes across this question since it seems related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the built in button **types** and corresponding `CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_*` classes that are invoked when those buttons are clicked.

For example, clicking on a button created with

```
$this->addButtons(array(
  array(
    'type' => 'submit',
    'name' => ts('Submit'),
    'isDefault' => TRUE,
  ),
));
```

Will call `CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Submit->perform()` which redirects you to the value of `$form->controller->_destination` (and if `$form->controller->_destination` is not set, will display the form again).

So in the simplest case, you can just add a line along the lines of the following to your form:

```
$this->controller->_destination = CRM_Utils_System::url('civicrm/something', 'reset=1');
```

Probably the best way to understand the other actions is to have a look at the `perform()` methods in the `CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Submit_*` classes.

GinkgoFJG's answer (and possibly Erik's) works when the button type is 'done', which makes sense when you have a look at the comments the inline code documentation for `CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Done->perform()`.

```
// Processes the request.
// [...] validate the page
// and if success, call post process
// when done processing pop to user context
```

Comment: Michael, you did quite some investigation...but is not totally clear to me. So what do I do if I want to 'interrupt' the form processing and end it what do I do exactly?

Comment: @ErikH-CiviCooP - hmm, would you like to flesh out some details - maybe as a new question? - and I'll do my best to answer as I think that the answer probably depends on what exactly you mean by 'interrupt' and 'end' :)

Comment: will do. I have a solution but it might be interesting for other visitors too :-)

Comment: Here is my new question: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19743/recommended-way-to-deal-with-delete-action-in-a-page

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I do in a page:

```
$session = CRM_Core_Session::singleton();
$session->pushUserContext(CRM_Utils_System::url('civicrm/pumexpenseclaims/page/claimlevel', 'reset=1', true));
```

Then in the form I do nothing in the postProcess. The only thing I take into consideration is when I press something like delete on the page where I take an action but do not need a form. If that is the case I tend to do this:

```
$session = CRM_Core_Session::singleton();
CRM_Utils_System::redirect($session->readUserContext());
```

Mind you, it could well be that this pattern no longer works in 4.7? What are the issues you run in to?

Comment: when you say "in a page", where do you mean, specifically? I've added a call to pushUserContext in buildQuickForm but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: In most cases I have a list of items on a page, which then leads to an action on a form? Strange that the pushUserContext has no effect....

Comment: Check this page https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.civirules/blob/master/CRM/Civirules/Page/Rule.php with this related form https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.civirules/blob/master/CRM/Civirules/Form/Rule.php

Comment: hey @erik. so in your code, a redirect, or similar, must be happening somewhere (in core, I presume) but I don't know where. Do you? Knowing where that happens might help me debug why it isn't happening in my case.

Comment: I do not know either, I would expect that at some point in the CRM_Core_Form it would revert back to the user context?

Comment: Would be good to know what type of button you are using on these pages, Erik

Comment: I am not really using any button, when the user presses saves or cancel they go back to the userContext?

Comment: saves and cancel are buttons :) looking at https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.civirules/blob/master/CRM/Civirules/Form/Rule.phphttps://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.civirules/blob/master/CRM/Civirules/Form/Rule.php they have the type next and cancel.

Comment: Allright, you mean in that sense :-) Yes I use the cancel and save buttons, with next and cancel type.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to set the userContext in my page, which will then make my form return to where I wanted it. Does that make sense?

Comment: I did try doing that, but didn't get it working - do you want to expand on your answer with an example? stackexchange will reward your quality answer handsomely, I am sure ;)

Comment: If you could also explain if there is anything to take into account when the page is loaded via a pop up vs normally, many riches will flow your way...

Answer (score 1):

Here's how Volunteer does it:

- Form class [declares](https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.volunteer/blob/fcebff0828181884908d5030775e95f08a7ca7a8/CRM/Volunteer/Form/VolunteerSignUp.php#L45-L52) a property `$_destination`.
- During the `preProcess` stage, a method [`setDestination()`](https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.volunteer/blob/fcebff0828181884908d5030775e95f08a7ca7a8/CRM/Volunteer/Form/VolunteerSignUp.php#L743-L769) decides how to set that property based on context.
- During the `postProcess`, [`CRM_Core_Session::singleton()->pushUserContext($this->_destination);`](https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.volunteer/blame/fcebff0828181884908d5030775e95f08a7ca7a8/CRM/Volunteer/Form/VolunteerSignUp.php#L450) takes care of the redirect. Note that doing it this way rather than using `redirect` is more [extensible](https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.volunteer/commit/0b140799d0f1cc9aea7736b1cf3497141e9fee1d).
- Ensure that the type of your submit button is 'done'.

Comment: This didn't work for me initially. I dug around in a few of the relevant classes `CRM_Core_Controller`, `HTML_QuickForm_Controller`, `CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action` and CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_*` * including *=Submit and *=Done and found that this approach works when the type of the submit button is 'done'.