# Recommended way to deal with delete action in a page?

Tags: extension, developer, forms, redirect

When developing extensions I have always followed this path when I had a page listing stuff (for example books) and an action link to delete the book:

1. Create the page and add a link to the form `CRM_Utils_System::url(/ "civicrm/myext/form/myform", "action=delete&reset=1", TRUE)`
2. In the form, pick up the delete action in the preProcess method like so:

   `if ($this->_action == CRM_Core_ACTION::DELETE) {
   //do my stuff
   $url = CRM_Utils_System::url("civicrm/myext/page/mypage", "reset=1", TRUE);
   CRM_Utils_System::redirect($url);
   }`

I understood that I should not use the CRM_Util_System::redirect() but should use the `CRM_Core_Session::singleton->pushUserContext($url)` instead. But what is then the recommended way to ignore the rest of my form processing so that the controller returns to the userContext (being my page)?

Answer (score 3):

**The way I did it**

In my most recent extension with a fair amount of CRUD happening via the UI, I used a different form at a specific URL (civicrm/sms/conversation/confirmdelete) for deleting. This gave the  user the chance to see what they were deleting and confirm it.

I then set the context in preProcess of that form, deleted the entity in postProcess, and let the controller handle redirection.

```
$this->context = CRM_Utils_System::url('civicrm/sms/conversation/view', "id={$this->conversationId}");
$this->controller->_destination = $this->context;
$session->pushUserContext($this->context);
```

IIRC, it was setting `$this->controller->_destination = $this->context;` that enabled the magic to happen in postProcess, and mean that I didn't have to add any calls to `CRM_Utils_System::redirect()`.

FWIW I generalised this form to allow it to delete any of the entities that my extension was creating.

See the form here: 
https://github.com/3sd/civicrm-sms-conversation/blob/master/CRM/SmsConversation/Form/ConfirmDelete.php

**Is this the CiviCRM way?**

Since I wasn't sure how 'CiviCRM' this method was, I just had a quick look at how we handle deleting *contacts* and *membership types*.

***Contacts***

For contacts, the URLs look as follows:
civicrm/contact/view/delete?&reset=1&delete=1&cid=2 which maps to CRM_Contact_Form_Task_Delete, i.e. a special form, just for deleting contacts, which (although I haven't looked in details) seems to be a bit like what I did.

***Membership types***

civicrm/admin/member/membershipType/add?action=delete&id=1 maps to CRM_Member_Form_MembershipType. Looking at [the class](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Member/Form/MembershipType.php) and its [associated template](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/templates/CRM/Member/Form/MembershipType.tpl)

**preProcess** sets an appropriate context (this is where you would put your URL to your 'page listing stuff', I think).

```
$url = CRM_Utils_System::url('civicrm/admin/member/membershipType', 'reset=1');
$session->pushUserContext($url);
```

It also assigns the action to the template

```
$this->assign('action', $this->_action);
```

**buildForm** checks to see if this is a delete action, and if so, just returns, since it doesn't need to add any form elements

```
if ($this->_action & CRM_Core_Action::DELETE) {
  return;
}
```

**postProcess** does a similar check

```
public function postProcess() {
  if ($this->_action & CRM_Core_Action::DELETE) {
    try {
      CRM_Member_BAO_MembershipType::del($this->_id);
    }
...
```

And the template has a similar if else

```
{if $action eq 8}
  <div class="messages status no-popup">
    {ts}WARNING: Deleting this option will result in the loss of all membership records of this type.{/ts} {ts}This may mean the loss of a substantial amount of data, and the action cannot be undone.{/ts} {ts}Do you want to continue?{/ts}
  </div>
  <div> {include file="CRM/common/formButtons.tpl"}</div>
{else}
```

**So what is the right way?**

No comment :) You decide.